# Ranking an array of string rows by score

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ranking

I need to create a new array of string rows from an input one. The input array contains just a country name followed by its score. My goal is to recreate this array by adding one more value, which is the rank that the country will appear. Please, check out my skeleton code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="myRankFunction( ['AFG\t3,416', 'AUS\t1,414', 'BRA\t2,073', 'JPN\t1,316'] )">Rank</button>
<script>
/*
* The function must return a new rowlist in the format: 
*   Rank[TAB]Country[TAB]Score
*   - notice that the input rowlist DOESN'T contain the "Rank" part in the begining of the row;
*   - Rank is an integer number which represents the country's position in the ranking;
*   - Score is a float number; more Score means better Rank.
*/
function myRankFunction(rowlist)
{
    var newrowlist = [];
    var s1 = [], s2 = [];
    for(i = 0; i < rowlist.length; i++)
    {
        s1 = rowlist[i].split("\t");
        for(j = 0; j < rowlist.length; j++)
        {
            // ignores the current row
            if(i == j) 
            {
                continue;
            }
            s2 = rowlist[j].split("\t");
            if( s1[1] > s2[1] )
            {

            }
            else if( s1[1] < s2[1] )
            {
            }
            else 
            {
            }           
        }
    }   
    return newrowlist;  
}
</script>
```

For the example above, the function should return:

```
['1[TAB]AFG[TAB]3,416', 
 '2[TAB]BRA[TAB]2,073',
 '3[TAB]AUS[TAB]1,414',
 '4[TAB]JPN[TAB]1,316']
```

Comment: Why don't you just sort the array? Then the rank is the new array indexes+1.

Comment: First of all, "bored" is a poor excuse to ask for help and quit working. Second, I would sort the array and use it's own index as a rank. If you want to display rank somewhere, use `index + 1` 
[Here](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/) is some additional reading on sorting if you want to write it yourself

Comment: Barmar and PremierBromanov: I've tried to sort the scores, but after doing it I don't know how to reorder each string row based on the sorted scores. Forgot to say that some of the countries may have the same score. This also complicated me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
['AFG\t3,416', 'AUS\t1,414', 'BRA\t2,073', 'JPN\t1,316'].sort(function(a,b){
  //retrieving the rank by splitting the entry and return true or false to the sort callback function
  //in order to sort by rank 1,2,3 ...
  return(a.split('\t')[1]<b.split('\t')[1])
}).map(function(e,i){
  //creating a new array from the sorted array
  //adding the rank (using the index) - have to add 1, since index starts at 0
  return (i+1)+"\t"+e;
})
```

Comment: It would be nice, if you could add some explanation to your solution. That way, others who are not into the topic, can understand the answer easier.

Comment: topheman, thanks for your code. However, I tested it and it's returning AUS in second place, instead of BRA.

Comment: I get : `["1 AFG 3,416", "2 BRA 2,073", "3 AUS 1,414", "4 JPN 1,316"]`

Comment: Sorry, my faulty, It's working fine. Thank you so much for your code and for the explanation!